# Approximate Sign

Tags: symbols

how can I obtain the following approximate symbol.

[image: approx]

Thank you.
bkarpuz

Comment: It's `$\simeq$` (source: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: It's generally used to denote an isomorphism.  The approximate symbol is `≈` (command `\approx`).